# Syncing TortoiseHG with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, synchronization, continuous-integration, tortoisehg

I'm new to this continuous integration thing. I want to use Jenkins as my CI system, but I can't get it to pull the build everytime there's a new one.

Using mercurial's plugin I'm able to connect to my repository and pull my builds normally, but I don't want Jenkins to keep polling, I want it to update the build only when there's a new one instead. On the plugin's wiki I found this:

> As of version 1.38 it's possible to trigger builds using push
>   notifications instead of polling. In your repository's .hg/hgrc file
>   add:
>
> ```
> [hooks] 
>
>   commit.jenkins = wget -q -O /dev/null <jenkins root>/mercurial/notifyCommit?url=<repository remote url>
>   incoming.jenkins = wget -q -O /dev/null <jenkins root>/mercurial/notifyCommit?url=<repository remote url>
> ```

For now I'm keeping Jenkis local, so I used this o my hgrc file:

```
commit.jenkins = wget -q -O /dev/null http://localhost:8080/mercurial/notifyCommit?url=<my repository remote url>
incoming.jenkins = wget -q -O /dev/null http://localhost:8080/mercurial/notifyCommit?url=<my repository remote url>
```

But builds aren't being triggered. Could someone help me?

**[UPDATE]**

I didn't pay attention to the wget command, which doesn't exist on windows. Installed it and it's still the same. Jenkins is not pulling the builds.

Comment: Are you committing on Linux or Windows?

Comment: Wind0ze doesn't have wget by default

Comment: Oh, it's Windows. Sorry, haha! Do I use cygwin to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must to have wget on PATH (I'll recommend native port of [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow), not Cygwin - or Bash in Win10)
2. Your hooks must be in working state
3. `wget ...` must produce the expected result

you have <strike>three</strike>now two possible points of failure and have to test all independently

---

- Does my hooks work?

Replace your current content of hooks with dumb billet like

```
  commit.jenkins = echo Commit hook here
  incoming.jenkins = echo Incoming hook here
```

and test hooks (in **console** for better visibility) by executing commit into repo with added hook and pull|push to it|unbundle anything. If you'll see hook output - they are usable

- Does Jenkins integration work?

After commit to repo you can perform task of hook by hand: run `wget -q -O /dev/null ...` and check results in Jenkins

Comment: Did exactly what you told me to. Now the hooks are working correctly. But when wget is executed, the console message says "/dev/null: No such file or directory".

Comment: @PedroCorso - `/dev/null` is *Nix blackhole only. Win-version - `nul:`